# Nodemailer with Gmail, issue with From and To

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I get an error using Nodemailer and NodeJS. I try to send an email using my website but I get an issue, the email is sent but I have the same Email for "from" and "to" on my Gmail interface...

Screenshot : http://glui.me/?i=g43rrwpgdy6voy5/2014-03-18_at_18.32_2x.png/

My code :

```
    var contact = req.body.contact;

    var compagny = contact.compagny;
    var email = contact.email;
    var object = contact.object;
    var message = contact.message;
    var to = 'myemail@gmail.com';

    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "myemail@gmail.com",
            pass: "*********"
        }
    });

    var options = {
        from: email,
        to: to, 
        subject: object,
        text: "Société : "+compagny+"\nEmail : "+email+"\nMessage : "+message
    }

    transport.sendMail(options, function(error, response) {
        if (error)
                console.log(error);
        else
                res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a silly mistake? Shouldn't you be using

```
 var from = 'myemail@gmail.com';
```

instead of

```
 var to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
```

?

Comment: No because I want to receive the email at "myemail@gmail.com", but I want to see who is sending an email... And "email" contains the email of the person who is sending an email using my website...

Comment: I am afraid gmail doesn't allow you to do that (it will overwrite the from email using the account you used). You can try using sendgrid or similar relay services that gives more feature or just simply include the user's email in the subject or body and parse it.